# Android thousands of points in chart

Tags: android, graph, charts, drawing, points

I tried to find answer for my question, but I wasn't lucky. I have an Android app where I have thousands of points which have an altitude data and I want to draw that data in graph. What app is doing now is drawing graph data to ImageView. But I want to add zoom functionality, because when there are too many points that graph is too contracted.

I dont want to draw it to larger image and then downsample it, because it will take much memory - there can possible be many of these graphs. And I tried MPAndroidChart library to create that graph, but when there were thousands of points it drastically slowed down app.

I don't know what is the best to do. What do you think? I hope that this isn't a duplicate question and if you know that someone tried to solve this question, please let me know. Thnaks a lot.

Comment: Are you talking about a line graph? How many points exactly will you render?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about a line graph. There can be ten thousands of points and more.

Comment: Yes, you said that. But "thousands" is quite vague. Are we talking about 5.000, or 500.000?

Comment: Ok, sorry. About 5.000 not 500.000.

Comment: I think 5.000 points should not be a problem with MPAndroidChart. Go to the playstore and check out the example app. It renders up to 30.000 smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complex stuff.

I can only recommand HelloCharts library that handles many things (including zoom): https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android